# struggling to connect a sql server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working on a package installation for my company.  We have a product that is used offline, so a local database is needed.  My install package moves a .mdf and .ldf file to it's proper directory, and my connection string will attach the database if it is not attached:

```
"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\DATA\\myDatabase.mdf;Initial Catalog=SIGamepresenterNG;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
```

The problem is that the database will only attach if I FIRST manually attach and un-attach it.  If I don't first do this, it give me a permissions exception.

Is there a fix for this, and if not, how do I work around this?

Update:

Here is the exact error:

> Unable to the physical file c:..\mydatabase.mdf. Operating system
>   error 5(Access is denied). Cannot attach the file 'mydatabase.mdf' as
>   mydatabase

Comment: `it give me a permissions exception.` What **exactly** is that exception?

Comment: If I'm not mistaking just moving the mdf/ldf to the correct possitions does not let the sql server add a database and start serving it. I'd rather create a backup (bak), and restore that programatically so the server knows the database.

Comment: I'll have to uninstall and re-install sql server to get the error back, but it was something like 'Access denied for user 'my user id'.

Comment: you are using windows credentials to access the database : TrustServerCertificate=True.  Your user account has to be in the same user group as the SQL database.  Usually these issues are caused by putting the mdf file name into the connection string.  It is not needed since you have the SQL Server in the connection string.  The server has the file attached to the database to you do not need to include the mdf file also.  Using the mdf file will cause credential exceptions because the database owns the mdf file and doesn't allow other users to also access the mdf file.

Comment: Here is the exact error:  Unable to the physical file c:\..\mydatabase.mdf.  Operating system error 5(Access is denied).  Cannot attach the file 'mydatabase.mdf' as mydatabase

Comment: @jdweng - when I set TrustServerCertificate=Fase, everything works perfectly.  The installer copies the file to the sql server directory, and my connection string automatically attaches the .mdf file.

Comment: Does the database using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) see the changes?

Comment: A little more info:  My installation package first installs SQL Server 2012 and then my application.  After the install, the application tries to connect, but fails with an 'Unable to load the physical file, operating system error 5(Access is denied).  To solve this problem, I simply navigate to the 'Data' folder.  It prompts me that I will have permissions after I navigate there, so after I do so, the folder has permissions, and I am able to connect with my application.  So, I need to either figure out a way to give that folder permissions upon installation, or go about this another way.